# How do I chase a string down to the line of code, method name, class name and assembly that it was created in?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos

A dump of the GC heap of my managed process revealed that there were plenty of, among other types, large string objects.

I zeroed in on a couple of them:

```
> dumpheap -type System.String
> !do <address>
```

That told me what the contents of the string are, among other things that I wasn't very interested in.

So, I followed the string down to its GC root. But first, I wanted to confirm that it was on LOH.

```
> !gcwhere <address>
> !gcroot <address>
```

Now that's about as far as I could get.

I'd like to know where (which line of code created it, preferrably !dumpil of that line) along with the method description of the method that created it, the declaring type of that method, the assembly and the app domain that the assembly was loaded in.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework does not need that information for the application to run, so it does not store it. There's also no flag similar to the GFlags `+ust` setting that would activate such a storage. It's not possible with what you have as tools right now (a dump file or live debugging).

You need a memory profiler like [ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/). Even those do not collect allocation data by default and you have to activate it.

Screenshot of dotMemory:

[image: dotMemory Screenshot]

Comment: Thsnk you. I've got a dotMemory license. I'll use that.

Comment: dotMemory is able to collect objects allocations from the start, you need check "Collect allocation immediately" checkbox when starting your application under profiler.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/2017.1/Configuring_Profiling_Process.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. I am presently using the evaluation version while awaiting my license key. The evaluation version has the **Check allocation immediately** checkbox disabled and doesn't have the **Collect Allocations** button Thomas mentions in his answer.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: wow, what a limitation on the demo version. How do they want to win customers like that? Perhaps report it as a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FIDEA

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2
There is no any limitations during trial period. "Check allocation immediately" is disabled and "Collect allocations" button is absent when you **attach** to your process instead of starting it from dotMemory. It's impossible to collect allocation data in attach mode due to MS Profiling API restriction. See that answer for details
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483590/why-dotmemory-cant-collect-memory-traffic-and-stack-trace-info-when-try-to-atta/27486340#27486340

Comment: @Ed.ward Thing is: I am attaching to Winword.exe, an unmanaged process with a couple managed add-ins loaded in it, the behavior of which I am interested in inspecting. So, I did not *attach* because it allows you to attach only to managed processes. What I did instead was -- I selected **Profile Application** -> **Standalone** and chose the path to winword.exe. Strangely, though, the checkbox appears enabled now when I do the same thing.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: that's identical to attaching. Try setting the executable of your project in the project properties, then choose "profile startup configuration"