# (How) can I enable allocation data collection when profiling with dotMemory CLT

Tags: dotmemory

I'm getting comfortable with [dotMemory CLT](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/Working_with_dotMemory_Command-Line_Profiler.html) and **I'd like to understand if/how I can enable the collection of allocation data with a command line flag.**

With the API, I'm aware of the ability to leverage [`MemoryProfiler.EnableAllocations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483590/why-dotmemory-cant-collect-memory-traffic-and-stack-trace-info-when-try-to-atta), and with the desktop application I simply check a box

[image: Image showing the check-box I'm referencing]

But I find no references to this concept with respect to the CLT.

Attempting to use `start` doesn't do the trick, and poring over `dotMemory help start` doesn't reveal anything promising.

Is this simply not-supported, or am I missing/mis-understanding a critical section of documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line copied from  `dotMemory.exe help start |more`

```
[--collect-alloc|-c] Collect callstack allocation data (impacts performance!)
```

Example: `dotMemory start "C:\Path\To\YourProgram.exe" -c`

Comment: added `-c` and still got no memory traffic recorded. Shouldn't it work with `start-windows-service` also?

Comment: @python_kaa we checked it and it works with windows service. Could you please create a ticket in our bug tracking system https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/dmry and attach sample dotMemory workspace and logs in trace mode to it?

  [--log-level=<level>]           Logging level: ERROR|WARN|INFO|VERBOSE|TRACE
  [--log-file=<file-path>]        Log file path. By default logs stored in %Temp%\JetLogs